# semantic ui transition works on chrome but not on firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, semantic-ui

i'm building a website using semantic ui, there is an html class i called content that i want to jiggle when it is visible on the screen wich i used jQuery "[inview event plugin](https://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin)" for and it works perfectly on chrome but not on firefox, the html code is

```
<div class="column">
    <h1><i class="icon circular square yellow inverted">JS</i></h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, .</p>
    <div class="ui fade reveal pop" data-content="javascript and jQuery" data-title="JS">
    <img src="images/js.png" alt="js" class="ui circular image visible content" />
    <img src="images/jsreveal.png" alt="js" class="ui circular image hidden content">
    </div>
</div>
```

the jQuery code is :

```
$('.content').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
if (visible == true) {

 $('.pop .content').transition({
animation: 'jiggle',
duration: 1000,
useFailSafe: true,
allowRepeats: false,
queue : false
        });
```

}
});

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve the required jiggle animation functionality on both browsers - Chrome and Firefox with click event handler. It appears that the binding of inview handler is not correct here.
Refer http://jsfiddle.net/vaibhav_saxena/30qfv5km/

```
$('.content').on('click', function () {
    $('.content').transition({
        animation: 'jiggle',
        duration: 500,
        useFailSafe: true,
        allowRepeats: false,
        queue : false
    });
});
```